How long can nuclear power plants last without the power grid and humanity?
Here is the question: "Following an immediate, irreversible collapse of the power grid and the medium-term (few decades) disappearance of humanity, would would happen to nuclear power plants?"
An alternate question is the same as the question above, but the power plant's staff don't disappear.
For the plant itself, assume it's this one: Prairie Island Nuclear Plant in Minnesota. This may seem extremely specific, but it's relevant if you know the context.
The context isn't necessary, but if you want to know it, here it is:

All humans and human-created structures on mainland continents disappear. All islands are spared from this fate (being defined as separated from the mainland by a natural body of water, so inland islands count). That's why the power plant is so specific.


To Ash's point about spent fuel: does a 14-foot tube of manufactured alloy, which contains multiple pellets of painstakingly refined material, count as a "human-created structure" for purposes of your apocalypse? If yes, then it seems safe to assume that all the nuclear material on the mainland, spent or otherwise, would disappear along with our gymnasia, aquaria, planetaria, et cetera.

@Tom It looks like nothing in the plant counts as a human-created structure, since it's on an island. Otherwise, I would wonder what happens when something disappears: does it magically vanish, or get broken so it doesn't work? Radioactive materials would still be very dangerous if disassembled.

@MichaelFoster I'm asking whether the spent nuclear fuel in the affected areas would disappear along with the containment structures that house the spent fuel. Because it appears to be the case that a nuclear fuel rod is actually a device in its own right. A fuel rod is less like post-consumer motor oil and more like an iPod. If all the vending machines in Oregon disappear, I'd expect fuel rods in OR to disappear too. But it's OP's apocalypse, so I'm asking. Apologies if my first comment was unclear.

Spent nuclear would absolutely disappear

What does "disappear" mean, then? If they simply vanish, does the earth have slightly less mass? If not, where do the radioactive atoms go?

What do you mean by "last"? Continue operating as a functioning power plant? Or just exist as a structure that can be identified as artificial without a radiation meter?

@ChristopherJamesHuff Probably the latter

There is no such thing as "THE" power grid, there are several independent or semi-independent power grids in Eurasia, some of them are coupled by HVDC lines allowing to borrow power in case of some serious power collapse. Also say wind turbines would be ther allowing rebuilding of the "power grid" past such a collapse, unless it's something fundamental in which case the power plants could plain go BOOM because say neutron absorbing rods suddenly stop absorbing neutrons, causing the cores to go overcritical without means to control.

Please note that although the question I linked as the referent duplicate asks a lot of questions, Stack Exchange changed their rules since that time and only one question can be asked per post. See the "Needs More Focus" close reason.

Finally, it could be argued that your question should be closed as Needs More Details. The "power grid" includes power generation, raw material sources, distribution wires, substations, the termination conditions (e.g. buildings) and a fair number of other things. They would all eventually break down - and all at different rates for different reasons. Thus, the question has no single objective answer.

On thing to consider is that, given the nature of your proposed disaster, the United States (and some other nations, to a lesser extent) would still have a large number of reactors operating perfectly while afloat at sea. We have a fleet 11 aircraft carriers each with two nuclear reactors, as well as a host of various nuclear-powered submarines, all of which would continue to operate, more or less until they ran out of nuclear fuel. Depending on when they were last refueled, that could be quite a long, long time, barring any other failures. But after the fuel was spent, that would be the end.

Most power plants, nuclear and otherwise, are going to automatically go into shutdown once the grid stops drawing power. The biggest issue at nuclear plants is then one of the spent fuel, which if you've removing the structures it's stored in is going to immediately combust on contact with the air and kill everything for miles around, unless it is removed with them.
Prairie Island still being staffed will be safe from this immediate issue so it's all about keeping the pool topped off, and component failure in the pumps that move coolant around the site is the biggest threat.
Edit because AlexP makes a good point; if Prairie Island is allowed to go into full shutdown then the coolant pumps will be reliant on backup generators with finite fuel reserves, when that runs out the pool starts to dry out and then starts to burn.

This may be far-fetched, but how long can a power plant last shut down? If there’s nobody around, will it eventually become inoperable?

@Baudshaw: Until the fuel runs out for the emergency diesel generators running the cooling pumps. After that, you don't want to be around.

And that diesel fuel will last for only 7 days before it runs out and... meltdown

@SurpriseDog The reactor itself should be in cold shutdown by the time the diesel runs dry so the core should be safe from anything that doesn't rupture the contaminant vessel. The spent fuel pool on the other hand will boil down to the top of the rods in the space of a few hours and since spent fuel is Pyrophoric the pool will then explode into flames. In theory staff on site can keep the plant online to keep the pumps running but I'd be pouring cement and then Lead as fast as possible.

Diesel is only good for a year or so before it needs to be replaced. I wonder how the plant operators get rid of their old diesel. Do the sell it? Burn it off?

@SurpriseDog That depends on the formal and informal policies at the plant. If my experience at data centres is a guide, what "should" happen is that the it's consumed and replaced during routine tests of the backup power system. If it's a bit more of a cowboy operation, the tests never get done and the diesel is stolen by the staff and/or has gone manky in the tank so the generator doesn't start and everything goes dark once the UPS batteries run out. One hopes that a nuclear plant has somebody with authority ensuring that the tests are done and the diesel topped-up.

Do any NPPs use solar+batteries for backup? If so, that'd last longer than generators+fuel, unless the fuel tanks were incredibly large. On a decent-sized island there might be other solar/battery installations that could be repurposed. Long term, you might be able to redirect river water to cool without pumping, or move the fuel into the river (unsafe for life downstream, but if you're the only ones left...)

@user51614 For backup purposes, solar+batteries is most likely treated identically to batteries.  You can't rely on solar to be working on any given day, so they would not design a failsafe system that is dependent on it.  Backups are typically a more predictable source of energy.

It's going to depend on details about the safety systems at the plant. I'm no expert on nuclear plant engineering so I'll yield if someone who is chimes in here. But in the US, at least, nuclear plants have built in safety system so that they will automatically shut down if anything dangerous happens.
If the staff were all killed in the plague that wiped out humanity or whatever, then odds are SOMETHING would go wrong before too long, as there's nobody maintaining all the complex systems, and the power plant would shut down.
If the staff were still there, they could probably keep it running for a while. Until they ran out of spare parts and supplies. How long would that take? Depends on their stocks. A few months would be plausible. 100 years? Probably not.
In the US, politicians have been arguing what to do about nuclear waste for decades, so in the meantime nuclear plants have to store their waste on site. So if the staff are still around, adding some spent fuel rods to the repository would probably not be a big deal.

US nuclear plants will shutdown as soon as the grid collapses, they are built that way as a saftey precausion.

Suppose the plant does shut down, but the operators know what's going on and wish to bring the plant up again. I'm curious how difficult it'd be to defeat/trick the safeguards such that the plant can be bootstrapped from the diesel generators, then keep itself powered. I know some deadtime is required for short-lived decay products/poisons to themselves decay, but would it be possible to bring back up before generator fuel ran out?

@user51614 That’s not just dependent on the generator fuel supply, but also the amount of power required for what amounts to a cold start. Circumventing the safeguards is easy enough though if you can get the required supplies, you just need to make an absurdly large electric heating element that can draw enough power to keep things above the minimum operational threshold (plus a bit extra as a safety margin).

No need to wonder, we have a real world example.  Fukushima is what happens when a nuclear plant is cut off from all power.

No thats what happens when a poorly build massively outdated plant is cut off at the same time its hit with a magnitude 9 earthquake. There is a reason no one builds reactors like that anymore.

@John The main damage was because the cooling failed.  The reactor will still produce 3% power when the cooling is lost.

@LorenPechtel Saying that the main damage was "because the cooling failed" makes it sound like the main damage was from a meltdown; rather, it was explosions caused by a buildup of hydrogen gas, which comes from the high temperatures and contact with steam and the zirconium cladding that holds the fuel. The reason I make the distinction is that, since the Three Mile Island incident, the NRC requires US power plants to have systems in place to mitigate any buildup of hydrogen that might come from a loss of cooling accident.

@Amocito And those systems will work without power??

I mean, yes. Just a passive catalyst bed and a battery that can produce a spark would be a significant improvement.

@LorenPechtel the main damage was caused by the tsunami, many many systems failed when swamped by seawater and hit by the massive force of the wave.  Power loss had nothing to do with it. The plant could and did handle power loss many times.

@John Power loss, go to generators.  The generators failed.

The generatos failed because they were hit by a tsunami, and the only reason they needed the generators is becasue the plant battery systems were shorted out by the tsunami and the next backup cooling system was crushed by the tsunami. the generators were the third backup system, saying the plant failed because they failed is like saying the trade centers building caught fire because  the fire extiquisher canisters in the janitors closet was empty.

@John The cooling systems were worthless without the generators to power them.  You don't passively dissipate that much heat.  The failure point was the generators running out of fuel.  Nothing that did or didn't come before that was relevant.

Actually you can passivelt dissapate the heat of a reactor once it has gotten into shutdown. which is what the batteries were for. the first backup was to use the reactors own residual power to do run the intial cooling or failing that simple gravity fed water tanks. IF backup systems A, B, C and D ALL fail becasue of X, the the plant did not fail becasue D failed, they failed due to X.

@John Batteries run down.  Gravity fed tanks empty.  Generators are the only sustainable part of the system and they're only sustainable so long as the fuel lasts.

You missed the part where I said it wold run off the reactors own low output in the shutdown mode. All three of those other systems were just to get the hot reactor down to that shutdown. Realy just go read up on the reactor instead of guessing everything.
